# How to know what's causing screen backlight to fail? Dell XPS 13 9370

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, dell-xps, repair, backlight

I have a Dell XPS 13 9370 laptop which has an issue with its LCD screen backlight. The computer works perfectly with an external screen and you can see that the built-in display works (e.g. against a bright light). It's just the backlight that's off.

I tried disassembling the laptop but I found nothing that seemed off (i.e. no corrosion or loose connectors). I sent it to an authorized Dell repair shop for diagnostics and they concluded that the screen needs to be replaced because its LCD backlight is dead.

I ordered a new screen and replaced it myself. Unfortunately, the issue is still there. LCD panel works, but no backlight. Now I'm kind of pissed at the repair shop, as they likely didn't do a thorough investigation on what's wrong with it.

I'm now wondering what can I do to troubleshoot the issue further.

Is there any way to test what component is broken? I'm assuming it could be the power supply going to the screen but I want to make sure before purchasing yet another part.

Any tips on how to proceed further?

Comment: Since the external monitor works, you know the video is fine. I suspect a connection was not properly made when you replaced the screen. Try a local computer shop to see if they can connect the new screen.

Comment: The screen I installed was tested on a separate laptop, so it should be in good condition. When I installed the screen I made sure the connectors are clean and connected properly. The screen otherwise works, just no backlight.

Comment: That is why I suggest you have an experienced person look at it,

Comment: [This](https://www.laptopscreen.com/blog/tag/laptop-screen-backlight-not-working/) site suggests a blown fuse on the main board *might* be the culprit. You'd need good working knowledge of microelectronics, an electrical diagram of said main board, a suitable replacement fuse, a soldering iron with a very fine tip (and solder) and a very steady hand to replace one of these though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going to try fixing microcomponents on the motherboard myself. I'm just wondering if there's any sort of test I can do to check if it's the screen or the motherboard.